# HTML Form Field value alignment

Tags: html, css, forms

I have this code,

```
<span class='plabel'>Address</span> <span class='values'>: $address</span>
```

The CSS code :

```
.plabel { 
display:inline-block; 
width:100px; 
}

.values {
margin-left:50px;
}
```

Now when a value is displayed the value goes to the field where the field name is displayed.

Example,

```
Address : XXXX,
XXXX.
```

I want it to be,

```
Address : XXXX,
          XXXX.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap the `span` with a `div` and set fixed `width` for each one. Then use `float` for their position.

**html**

```
<div class="holder">
    <span class='plabel'>Address</span>
    <span class='values'>: Sotiris Val, Heraklion Crete, Greece</span>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.holder{width:220px;overflow:hidden;}
.plabel {
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    width:100px;
}

.values {
    width:120px;
    float:right;
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/48RDZ/

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine. Here is demo: http://jsfiddle.net/H2V7t/

```
<style type="text/css">
    .plabel {
display:inline-block;  
width:100px;
}

.values  {
margin-left:50px;
}

</style>
<div style="clear:both">
    <span class='plabel'>Address</span>  
    <span class='values'>: This  is the value number one on right cell</span>
</div>

<div style="clear:both">
    <span class='plabel'>Address</span>
    <span class='values'>: This is the value number two on right cell</span>
</div>
```